# Dropping all dates before value

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, panel-data

I have a panel dataframe of US states and dates.  My goal is to find the latest date for each state that has a 0 in a value column, and then drop all observations up to and including that point.  So as a MWE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state':['CA']*6+['MA']*6, 
               'date':list(pd.date_range('2000-1-1', freq='MS', periods=6))*2,
               'vals':[0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}).set_index(['state', 'date'])
```

Creates this df:

```
                  vals
state date
CA    2000-01-01     0
      2000-02-01     2
      2000-03-01     0
      2000-04-01     4
      2000-05-01     5
      2000-06-01     6
MA    2000-01-01     1
      2000-02-01     2
      2000-03-01     3
      2000-04-01     4
      2000-05-01     5
      2000-06-01     6
```

This finds the correct cutoff dates (open interval), allowing for the fact that MA has no zeroes and thus no cutoff date:

```
cutoff_dates = df.groupby('state').apply(lambda g: g[g['vals'] == 0].index.get_level_values(1).max())

state
CA   2000-03-01
MA          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But I haven't been able to go from this to filtering my dataframe so that I only have observations for CA beginning with 2000-4-1, and for MA from 2000-1-1.  I can see how this could be done by iterating over 'df' and 'cutoff_dates'.  **But how can it be accomplished within the Pandas and groupby environment?**  It seems like that should be possible, and I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a boolean mask and an intermediate group to filter out your dataframe:

```
m = df['vals'].eq(0)
g = m.cumsum()
out = df[~m & g.groupby(level=0).transform(max).eq(g)]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                  vals
state date            
CA    2000-04-01     4
      2000-05-01     5
      2000-06-01     6
MA    2000-01-01     1
      2000-02-01     2
      2000-03-01     3
      2000-04-01     4
      2000-05-01     5
      2000-06-01     6
```

Details about m & g:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, m.rename('m'), g.rename('g')], axis=1)
                  vals      m  g
state date                      
CA    2000-01-01     0   True  1
      2000-02-01     2  False  1
      2000-03-01     0   True  2
      2000-04-01     4  False  2
      2000-05-01     5  False  2
      2000-06-01     6  False  2
MA    2000-01-01     1  False  2
      2000-02-01     2  False  2
      2000-03-01     3  False  2
      2000-04-01     4  False  2
      2000-05-01     5  False  2
      2000-06-01     6  False  2
```